# How Intersection of Regular Language and a CFL is a CFL?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, context-free, pushdown-automata

CFL is not closed under intersection. That means, if we have L1,L2 of CFL then

```
L1 intersection L2 is not a CFL
```

And we know, all Regular languages are CFL. Then how it is true that intersection of Regular language (R1) (which is again a CFL) and a CFL(CL1) is a CFL?

```
R1 intersection CL1 should not be CFL right? becase R1 is again a CFL.
```

[image]

Comment: CFL is not closed under intersections means intersecting two CFL languages does not have to be in CFL but it still can be (for example the intersection of a CFL language with it self)

Comment: To understand this, I need to draw a product automata for a DFA and PDA? Can you please give some example?

Answer (score 3):

Every CFL language can be describes as a PDA. Every regular language can be described as a DFA.

The orthogonal product of a DFA and PDA can be defined as follows:

The new states of the automaton are all $(q_{PDA}, q_{DFA})$. That start state is $(s_{PDA}, s_{DFA})$ and the final states are all $(f_{PDA}, f_{DFA})$ where $f_{PDA}\in F_{PDA}$ and $f_{DFA} \in F_{DFA}$.

Given the transition of the PDA defined as $\delta_{PDA}(q_{PDA}, stack_{PDA}, a) = (q'_{PDA}, stack'_{PDA})$ and transition function of the DFA $\delta_{DFA}(q_{DFA})$

The transition function $\delta(q, a)$ for the new Automaton is where the transition function of the PDA is defined defined as $\delta((q_{PDA}, q_{DFA}), stack_{PDA}, a) = ((q'_{PDA}, \delta_{DFA}(q_{DFA})), stack'_{PDA})$

(in laymans terms, split out the states simulate the DFA and PDA independently and only accept the language when both are in a final state)

There is only 1 stack in this automaton. Thus it is a valid PDA. Therefor the language described by the intersection of a CFL and a regular language is a CFL.

The reason this does not hold for the intersection of 2 CFLs is because you need a second stack for second PDA.

Comment: I still could not understand how to construct a product automata for FA and PDA. Can you please give me a example with a diagram. Examples can be RL - c and CFL - a^nb^n. So, Σ* ∩ a^nb^n = a^nb^n - is a CFL. I have done the individual automatas and attached with the question. Please help me how to combine and proove that the final one is a CFL

Answer (score 0):

The sticking point is in the first statement:

> CFL is not closed under intersection. That means, if we have L1,L2 of CFL then
>
> > L1 intersection L2 is not a CFL

This is not what non-closure means. What it actually means is that the intersection of two languages from a given set *may* not be in the given set, so in this case "CFL is not closed under intersection" means that given two context free languages, their intersection might not be a context free language.

For many context free languages however,their intersection is context free.

As you note, and as Ratchet Freak proves, the intersection of a context free language and regular language is context free.

We can make more complicated examples though:

Let $L_{1} = \{0^{n}1^{n}\#0^{m}1^{k} \mid n,m,k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $L_{2} = \{0^{n}1^{m}\#0^{k}1^{k} \mid n,m,k \in \mathbb{N}\}$, then $L_{1} \cap L_{2} = \{0^{n}1^{n}\#0^{m}1^{m}\}$, which is still context free, and both $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$ are non-regular, so there's no extra restriction leading to the intersection being context free.